How to download .conda files?
I downloaded the
ncurses-6.4-h59595ed_2.conda 

file from the Anaconda website. I expected to manually install ncurses from the local file using the command
conda install ncurses-6.4-h59595ed_2.conda,

but I encountered the following error：
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/r/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fb5be5132b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))",),)

A reportable application error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?
[y/N]:
No report sent. To permanently opt-out, use

    $ conda config --set report_errors false


But old version in tar.gz format like ncurses-6.4-h59595ed_2.tar.bz2 installed just fine.
Could someone give me a suggestion on how to proceed? I have already navigated to the directory where the .conda file is stored when running the conda install command.

Which Conda version are you using? You can check version by command conda --version 

I am using conda version 4.5.4.

Your version of conda is too old.  You will need at 4.7.0 or newer.

The .conda package format was introduced in Conda v4.7, as you mentioned in comment, you currently using older version so try to update it by command:
conda update conda

Also you could try to install this package in offline mode, so please try this command:
conda install --offline ./ncurses-6.4-h59595ed_2.conda

The ./ tells conda to look in current dir
Also you could try to download and install .tar.bz2 package
conda install ./ncurses-6.4-h59595ed_2.tar.bz2

